# multi line comments in shell script - knowing details or documentation

Tags: shell, comments

After searching for options, I got to know we can add multi line comments inside a script with `:<<` but I don't see its documented in a man page.

```
$ :<<'SCRIPT_DOCU'
> my detailed documentaion here. ..
> multi-lined : can go here
> .
> .
> SCRIPT_DOCU
```

And man page doesn't lead me to what I am looking for :

`man "\:\<\<"`  or

```
man bash | grep "\:\<\<"
```

How do we get to know on such options available from a *unix environment?. can it be interpreted by some null command , as it begins with `:` ( typing just : on command line & hitting enter doesn't do anything ).

And after some more finding, there are few options like this one : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#COMMENTH ( though it doesn't allow me to use #+ in second line ) OR with something with dodging interpretation of single quote with

```
__='
something here
more of that. ..
'
```

Let me know on above options or shell interpreations in above cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
: is Shell Builtin Command

Unless otherwise noted, each builtin command documented in this section as accepting options preceded by - accepts -- to signify the end of the options. The :, true, false, and test builtins do not accept options and do not treat -- specially. The exit, logout, break, continue, let, and shift builtins accept and process arguments beginning with - without requiring --. Other builtins that accept arguments but are not specified as accepting options interpret arguments beginning with - as invalid options and require -- to prevent this interpretation.

: [arguments]
No effect; the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing any specified redirections. A zero exit code is returned.
```

In another words, : is to do nothing. But in your sample, it shows the menu in script only for your reference (after <<)

Comment: Thank you. Now I got some specific documentaion specific to interpretaion of : and -- . Adding link for others ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html. Do you know usage of '#, #+' and __ usages?.

Comment: `__` is just a variable name which is unlikely to be used, so you can safely assign to it without disrupting your program. It's no different from saying `foo='...'`. `#+` is just a convention; it has no special meaning to `bash`.

Comment: @BMW : to add response to your edit, in my case SCRIPT_DOCU specifies begin & end delimiter for specifying multi line comments. accepting your answer. ..

Comment: @chepner : If we use __ it has same effect of adding multi line comments. I was trying to understand shell interpretation in such cases..